# NUnit3 cannot find F# test when applied with RunInApplicationDomain attribute

Tags: f#, nunit-3.0

I am using VS2017 with NUnit Test Adapter 3.12.0 and

```
nuget NUnit 3.10.1 framework: >= net45
nuget NUnit.ApplicationDomain 11.1.0
nuget NUnit.Runners 3.9.0
```

I want to run each test in a separate domain but when applying `[RunInApplicationDomain]` attribute to a test, the test can't be found in the VS Test Explorer. Removing the attribute then it can be found. Is there a workaround?
For instance, the test below can not be found.

```
namespace Foo
open NUnit.ApplicationDomain
open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
type ThreeNodeTests() = 
    [<Test; RunInApplicationDomain>]
    member __.Test1() = 
        Assert.Pass()
```